# ORDER BY Case statement goes wrong for some reason

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I've got this `ORDER BY` SQL statement (programming in asp classic) and for some reasson I keep getting the error:

```
error '80004005'
/tools.asp, line 292
```

The error was there after updating my SQL with an order by case. The line 292 is also the excecuting statement of the SQL. So obviously something goes wrong with my Order by Case statement but I really have no clue what..

**My SQL:**

```
strSQLtw = "SELECT * FROM tariefnummers WHERE TariefOpWeb=TRUE AND Tariefnummer IN ('CD','CS','CG','DR','CA','CF','FD','FM','FR','BF','BW') ORDER BY CASE WHEN Status = 'CD' THEN 1 WHEN Tariefnummer = 'CS' THEN 2 WHEN Tariefnummer = 'CG' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END"
   Set rstTw = Con.Execute(strSQLtw)
```

Comment: Can you confirm it works if you remove the `ORDER BY` ? That looks like a connection error code

Comment: Why do you presume it's the order by?  It looks like a login failure to me...  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306586  *(Quick internet search of "SQL Server error 80004005")*

Comment: `TariefOpWeb=TRUE` isn't going to work, unless there's a column with the sane name.

Comment: @StuartLC There is a column (boolean) with the same name.

Comment: @AlexK. when I remove the order by it works like it should. If I do a 'normal' order by Tariefnummer ASC it works as well..

Comment: @MatBailie that wouldnt explain the fact that it is working normal when removing the order by.

Comment: add a breakpoint on that line, copy the sql and execute it directly on the database and see what the error it give you

Comment: @Tanner Good idea, executed the query in my database and got the following error: `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(CASE ~~~etc)'`. That made me realize that I am programming in an Access database and not SQL server, no clue if I can use the case in Access selects and if not what else to use?

Comment: Alright.. so really stupid but was programming in Access not realizing that I   still was using my SQL server syntax.. So fixed it now by using a Switch statement since case doesnt work in Access. Thank you anyway people!

Comment: @Nicolas based on what you've said, the accepted answer isn't valid, you'd be better off adding an answer yourself with your actual fix, including the explanation, and accepting that rather than an answer that may mislead future users.

Comment: @Tanner Ah yeah, was wondering how I could do it in the best way. Will do!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
strSQLtw = "SELECT * FROM tariefnummers WHERE TariefOpWeb=TRUE AND
            Tariefnummer IN ('CD','CS','CG','DR','CA','CF','FD','FM','FR','BF','BW') 
            ORDER BY CASE Tariefnummer WHEN 'CD' THEN '1' WHEN 'CS' THEN '2' WHEN 'CG' THEN '3' ELSE '4' END"

Set rstTw = Con.Execute(strSQLtw)
```

Comment: How does CASE WHEN Status = 'CD'  become CASE Tariefnummer WHEN 'CD' ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was using an SQL Server language while using an Access database. The Access SQL doesnt accept ORDER BY CASE. Fixed it with a Switch statement instead.